# fix for MAYTAG MDB8959AWW JETCLEAN PLUS SERIES FULLY INTEGRATED DISHWASHER

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

We bought this dishwasher machine in 2011. It worked fine for the last 6 years. Then, recently we noticed that several times it worked through the whole night, and then finished. I noticed yesterday that it takes a long time for it to start the cycle. I noticed that it stays quite for a long time with option "Steam Clean" flushing. I opened it, and tried to reprogram it to auto clean and normal, but buttons either did not lit up, or switched to "Steam Clean" flushing quickly after I close the machine. I even tried to switch off the breaker for a minute, but it did not help. Then I left it with blinking "Steam Clean" button. And apparently it started the cycle during the night, but it finished it only on the morning. We just had a technician, and he said it is probably the control panel, but needs to do some research.

Model of the dishwasher is as the following:

MAYTAG MDB8959AWW JETCLEAN PLUS SERIES FULLY INTEGRATED DISHWASHER WITH 6 WASH CYCLES, DURAGUARD NYLON RACKS, 6 HOUR DELAY START, SILVERWARE BLAST SPRAY JETS AND SILENCE RATING OF 56 DB: WHITE

I am wondering:

1. What can be the problem?
2. Can I fix it myself?
3. What should be a ballpark for a cost to fix it in LA? Or, is it better to buy a new machine at this point?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the control board can be purchased on line for ~130$. If the service tech was not sure that would bother me as they get called all the time to fix machines.

Comment: I cold my technician and he told me the total (panel and work) will be $250.

Comment: I googled maytag your model and the word parts there were several sites I did not look at all of them. I did try to find if there were other reports but came up with your post on the stackexchange. The parts breakdown of the door shows the screws so it should not be two hard to replace the board / box if you are handy with basic tools you may save 100$.